# PHP regex back reference in a conditional pattern - subpattern always defined

Tags: php, regex

I have a little regex represented in a simplified form below:

```
/\<((div|span)|(img|link)).*?(?(3)\/?>|.*?\<\/\\2>)/
```

This means that the subpatterns should be:

1. the tag name
2. tag names with closing tags
3. tag names with no closing tags

The purpose is quite obvious: if I match a tag with a closing tag such as div or span, look for the closing tag. If it's img or link, etc, just look for the end of the opening tag.

The problem is that, though subpattern 3 is empty when it matches a div or span, for the conditional pattern it seems to be defined.

On this simplified version it works, but on the full regex it refuses to work unless I use a simple OR (no closing tag pattern|closing tag pattern). So I'm wondering if I'm missing some pitfalls of back references in conditional subpatterns. I'll note that I have also tried using relative references and this didn't help.

Very grateful for any advice.

Cheers,

Comment: Your regex does not account for nested tags.

Comment: As I said, this is a simplified version just to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Please post the string to repro the issue.

Comment: You can show [on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/sL1wS1/1) what's not working (changed `\\2` to `\2`). Or [here one without conditionals](https://regex101.com/r/oK1sH1/1).

Comment: @bobblebubble the \\2 isn't the issue, but good idea to simplify and replace the conditional, will try that

Comment: `On this simplified version it works, but on the full regex it refuses to work` then we need your actual regex pattern.